# Async Issue using NPM Package and Meteor.wrapAsync

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

When using a function `client.call` from an npm module (`node-celery`), it appears that the callback function of `client.call` is not executed.

```
Meteor.methods({
    'estimates.request'(data) {
        var celery = require('node-celery')
        var client = celery.createClient({...})

        client.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('connected');                   // this is executed
            client.call('proj.tasks.register', [name],
                function(err, result) {
                    console.log('result: ', result);    // this is not executed
                    client.end();
                    return result;
                }
            );
        });
    }
});
```

Tried wrapping `client.call` in `Meteor.wrapAsync`:

```
callFunc = client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('connected');                   // this is executed
    client.call('proj.tasks.register', [name],
        function(err, result) {
            console.log('result: ', result);    // this is not executed
            client.end();
            return result;
        }
    );
});

callFuncSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(callFunc)
callFuncSync()
```

but this throws an error in the Meteor server console:

```
err:  [Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.]
err:  { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
```

**Question:** How should we use `Meteor.bindEnvironment` to fix this issue?

Comment: Why don't you create a single connection to celery and simply use it for all method calls? right now, you are creating the client every time someone calls the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs,

> Wrap a function that takes a callback function as its final parameter. The signature of the callback of the wrapped function should be `function(error, result){}`

Your code simply wraps the return value of the event attachment call.

You could wrap the whole thing (connection + task calls), but in your case, I would suggest a different approach:

Right now, you are connecting to Celery every time someone is calling the method. I would advise having a persistent connection to Celery, if possible.

The functions that you are trying to wrap do not adhere to the `wrapAsync` requirements, so you would have to wrap them in a function that does.

In the following code, both the connection and call functions are taken care of. Note that those functions take a `cb` argument, which will be provided to them by Meteor, and call it with an error and/or result, as appropriate.

those functions are then passed to `wrapAsync`.

The sync version of them throws if an error is passed to the callback and simulate a synchronous run using a fiber if they are called in a synchronous manner (i.e, no callback is passed). That's the reason for the `try..catch` block.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
const celery = require('node-celery'); // or `import` it

function createAndConnectAsync(details, cb) {
    const client = celery.createClient(details);
    const errHandler = function(e) {
        cb(e, client);
    };
    client.once('connect', function() {
        client.off('error', errHandler);
        cb(null, client); // success
    });
    client.once('error', errHandler);
}

function callAsync(client, task, args, cb) {
    client.call(task, args, function(result) {
       cb(null, result);
    });
}

const createAndConnect = Meteor.wrapAsync(createAndConnectAsync);
const call = Meteor.wrapAsync(callAsync);

let client;
try {
   client = createAndConnect({...}); // returns after the client is connected
} catch(e) {
    // connection error
}

Meteor.methods({
    'estimates.request'(data) {
        // generate `name`
        const result = call(client, 'proj.tasks.register', [name]);
        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! When I try out your solution, an error `Exception in callback of async function: Error: Future resolved more than once` occurs. Traced it down to `const result = call(client, 'proj.tasks.register', [name]);` as commenting that line out (and removing `return result`) will avoid the error. Any ideas?

Comment: It's also probably `client.off('error', errHandler());` causing the error, commenting it out removes the error, but now `call(client,...)` does not seem to return anything

Comment: That was my editor outsmarting me and me not noticing (see my edit). Of course, no use of invoking the callback when trying to remove it. Anyway, the code in this answer is quite rudimentary, and intended to mainly explain how to apply `wrapAsync` for pretty much any function.

Comment: Also note that the available functionality varies depending on your backend.  If you decide to use the npm package, take a look at its examples and source. There are no proper API docs, so in this case I took a look at the source code. If your call did not return, it is likely that your task never completes. You may [`expire`](https://github.com/mher/node-celery/blob/master/examples/expiration.js) it.

Answer (score 2):

Combinding async libraries can be tricky, usually they have some helper methods like Meteor's [bindEnvironment](https://www.eventedmind.com/items/meteor-what-is-meteor-bindenvironment).

> The function returned from Meteor.bindEnvironment also automatically gets run in a Fiber.

```
Meteor.methods({
    'estimates.request'(data) {
        var celery = require('node-celery')
        var client = celery.createClient({...})

        var otherCallback = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, result) {
            console.log('result: ', result);    // this is not executed
            client.end();
            return result;
        });
        var connectCallback = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
          console.log('connected');                   // this is executed
          client.call('proj.tasks.register', [name], otherCallback);
        });
        client.on('connect', connectCallback);
    }
});
```

FYI: didn't test this because your example isn't 100% complete :)

Comment: You should accept @MasterAM answer, it is more complete.

Comment: Thanks, I started testing your solution first because its simpler. Why is `otherCallback` not executed? In my test, the `console.log` inside `otherCallback` did not run and the `result` was not returned to the client that called the `Meteor.method`

Comment: Perhaps you're just misusing the `celery`, I can't tell because you didn't include which celery package you're using. (There are many)  Maybe try this one instead [celeryjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/celeryjs)

Comment: I'm using [`node-celery`](https://github.com/mher/node-celery), I'll give `celeryjs` a try to see if it helps